# Order in Set theory and Logic

Tags: elementary-set-theory

In ZFC ordered pairs are often defined in terms of Kuratowski pairs $(x, y)=\{\{x\}, \{x, y\}\}$ or some other such construction to avoid introducing additional primitive notions. The definition is then usually followed by apologies because it implies artificial properties like $\{x\}\in (x, y)$ etc. which are then immediately ignored. This then leads to even weirder and more arbitrary relations down the line. Meanwhile the notion of an ordered strings is taken granted in the underlying logic e.g. $x\rightarrow y$. 
 Since strings are automatically equipped with order why not drop the requirement that order pairs are sets altogether and instead try to arrange something like  $(x, y)=xy$ for sets $x$ and $y$? (If we can use strings of length 1 to represent sets why not strings of length 2 to represent ordered pairs?) $(x, y)$ would then presumably be an urelement but not a set. This would have the advantage that all objects are constructed from sets even though not all are sets.

Comment: We want to put ordered pairs in sets. But the only thing we can put in sets are other sets. So we need to represent ordered pairs as sets.

Comment: Are you asking about the use of strings of symbols in the definitions of syntactic constructs like terms, formulas and proofs in logic?

Comment: I think your question could benefit from an example. As stated, I'm not sure what kind of order you have in mind.

Comment: Set theory employs an underlying logic which already includes a notion of ordered objects i.e. the strings of symbols that constitute the sentences of the formal language. Absent such strings there is no logical language and no theory of sets. I guess what I'm saying is that strings seem to be more fundamental than sets. If so why not simply define ordered pairs as strings of length 2? This has the advantage there are no accidental or junk theorems like those that accompany the Kuratowski definition.

Comment: The notion of a string of characters in logic is a metalanguage concept. Strings are not "objects of first order logic".

Comment: Note that the "ordered" pair construct a la Kuratowski does not really introduce an order among the constituents - it only makes itsconstituténts distinguishable. It is (just another) convention that for a Kuratowski pair $z$, we call $\bigcup\{\,t\in \bigcup z\mid \{t,t\}\in z\,\}$ the *first* component.

Answer (score 2):

Interesting question. A case *could* be made that set theory presupposes logic and that logic presupposes some notion of order (in addition to strings in a formal language, in a proof *later* statements depend on *earlier* statements). At best, this would show that Kuratowski's construction is not the *origin* of the notion of order.

Note that logic also presupposes a notion of sets (e.g. a theory is a set of statements). One of the goals of a formal set theory is to provide a rigorous foundation for such presuppositions. A formal theory of sets linked with an informal theory of order wouldn't provide an adequate foundation. The only real choice is between having a formal theory of sets such as we now have with ZFC and a formal theory of sets + order (something like ZFC extended with new primitives and new axioms). Since Kurtaowski's construction shows that we can get by with the former, the latter would just make the theory more complicated with no real benefit.

Comment: Since modifying ZFC leads to a different theory how can we be sure that there will be no real benefit?

Comment: The resulting theory (if done plausibly) will be a conservative extension of ZFC. Occams razor applies to foundations. Why multiply the primitives?  (If you want an ontologically rich foundation for mathematics -- why stop with adding order? Some plausibly argue that category theory can serve as a foundation).

Comment: Does a theory rife with accidental theorems really satisfy Occam's razor?

Answer (score 1):

A language that has no limitations on sentential self-reference is inherently inconsistent. (E.g. Sentence A says "B is false" and sentence B says "A is true".) In the set-theoretical systems ZF (Zermelo-Fraenkel) and ZFC, the limitation is 0. Strings of symbols in the formal language cannot be interpreted as assertions about other strings. Certain strings are called formulas and certain formulas are called sentences. Certain sentences are called axioms. Theorems are sentences derivable from the axioms by certain rules. We may introduce new symbols that are abbreviations for strings,  provided we do not introduce new axioms. (Unless that is our intent.)

$z=\{x,\{x,y\}\}$ is an abbreviation for the string $\forall u\;(u\in z\iff (u=x\lor [\forall s\ ;(s\in u\iff (s=x\lor s=y))])).$ From the axiom system ZF we can derive the theorem $\forall x,y \exists! z\;(z=\{x,y\}).$ And we can then insert the symbol $(x,y)$ for  $\{x,\{x,y\}\}$ wherever it appears in a formula.

Comment: "From the axiom system ZF we can derive the theorem…" I think you mean $\forall x, y \exists !z (z = \{ x, \{ x, y \} \})$.

Comment: "Strings of symbols in the formal language cannot be interpreted as assertions about other strings." The strings I was referring to weren't formulas. Does your remark still  apply?